# VSCode auto import - Not working for Rxjs operators

Tags: visual-studio-code, rxjs

I have a project where VS Code won't suggest imports when using rxjs operators.

```js
myObservable.pipe(
    take(1),
    filter(result => result),
    switchMap((result) => myOtherObserbable),
    finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)
)
```

In this scenario, `take`, `filter`, `switchMap` and `finalize` won't provide any suggestion in the contextual menu:

[image]

I have to manually write:
`import { take, filter, switchMap, finalize } from "rxjs/operators";`

And then it works.

What could cause that and where should I look for?

Answer (score 2):

Found out the issue in `tsconfig` file:

```json
"paths": {
    "@app/*": ["app/*"],
    "@env/*": ["environments/*"],
    "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
    "rxjs/*": ["../node_modules/rxjs/*"], // => Commenting this makes the imports work
    "@custom/library": ["../../../path/to/custom/library/src"]
}
```

I'm using a custom library and had to add paths for the project to know where to look, but apparently it brokes the auto import